# Where do I get potion ingredients?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

So far I've found monster guts in dungeon chests and as drops from crabs. Where else can I get various potion ingredients?

Answer (score 3):

Ingredients drop randomly from enemies. As you progress, you will either find lying around in dungeons & caves the ingredients or the game will decide to start dropping them as you progress to certain points. The order is Monster Guts, Monster Tails, and then Monster Horns. So just keep playing to unlock them all.

Comment: At what point will I start finding horns and tails?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I think I started finding those in Lorule.

Comment: After you first arrive at Lorule, all enemies, either from Hyrule or Lorule, will drop all 3 monster items.

Comment: IIRC, I started seeing them regularly from all monsters (in both worlds) after getting all three pendants. Only seeing monster guts if a few chests beforehand. (cc: @OrigamiRobot)